# Using 於ける and 中

Tags: meaning

I'm having some trouble seeing when it would be more appropriate to use one over the other. Could someone explain any difference in nuance, and perhaps put things into context with some examples?

Edit: I have seen the word 於ける on jisho.org as meaning in/at/for, but I am unable to locate any example sentences which contain it. So I suppose I would like to modify the intent of this question to request some examples of the word.

Comment: 於ける does not mean "inside" like I think you are thinking. It is not a synonym with 中, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not clear to me what you are asking about 中, I can tell you that the character 於 is used in phrases like に於{お}ける and に於{お}いて (meaning 'in; at; on; as for'). However, it should be noted that it is far more common for the phrases to be written in hiragana - における, において. That is why you are having difficulty finding examples - that kanji tends not to be used so much recently.

> 英語{えいご}は商業{しょうぎょう}**において**役{やく}に立{た}つ。English is useful in commerce. (*Source: Midori*).

So look for phrases like において or における and you will find a lot more examples. But it is likely that they will use hiragana rather than the kanji 於.